# I need to move my grid item from top to bottom but it doesnt work

Tags: grid

**Question**

I'm working on a CSS Grid layout, and I'm trying to achieve a specific behavior with the `box-1` grid item. My goal is to move it from top to bottom while keeping its size small. I've made adjustments to the `grid-row` property, but I'm encountering an error.

**Code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My grid experiment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="GRIDChalenge.css">
</head>
<body>
 <section class="grid-container">
        <div class="box-1">
            <h1>Save more and get visibility for your business</h1>
            <p>We can help expand your business by our community!</p>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="box-2">
           <h1>SMS marketing</h1>
           <p>We send convenient messages to our community to increase your earning!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-3">
            <h1>Paid media</h1>
            <p>We can advertize you on Youtube or social media!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-4">
            <h1>Website optimization</h1>
            <p>We can make your website ultra fast and responsive 
                to al ltypes of devices!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-5">
            <h1>Trusted parners</h1>
            <p>We leverage the power of connections to increase 
                your traffic at certain regions.</p>
        </div> -->
      
 </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    gap: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.grid-container .box-1 {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 5;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I'm trying to achieve something similar like with flex properties where you can freely move your items when you set up the alignment of the items. I just want  my "div" element to expand from top to bottom and move the item from the top side of the container to the bottom while its still small sized. Those are the 2 objectives I have